# Should I free allocated memory on abnormal termination?

Tags: c, free, malloc

My program (a text-mode web browser) is dynamically allocating memory.

I do free unneeded blocks during runtime, of course. And I do free everything before normal termination - so that memory leak checkers won't give me false positives (and to be flexible should major refactorings ever become needed).

Now, what I do *not* do is freeing memory before abnormal termination. (Currently, my program terminates on signals and after failed mallocs/reallocs.)

My question is: Do you consider this bad style? Should I free on abnormal termination?

Comment: your system will reclaim memory when your process terminates, won't it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  I think it's perfectly acceptable to simply throw up your hands and let the OS reclaim the memory after the program terminates.  I think if this is truly an abnormal situation and the intention is to have the program terminate, then a well-behaved program should simply clean up any disk resources/locks, and exit as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion freeing the memory on crash isn't necessary. When your process terminates, OS will reclaim the memory, so all you have to do is exit.

On the other hand, other resources (e.g. open files) should be closed or at least flushed -- if not, they may not be stored/stored incomplete because of the buffering.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* to reclaim memory on normal termination except to obviate false positives in leak detecting tools.

If your program  terminates abnormally, depending on the cause, you may find that you *can't* free memory.  For instance, a SIGSEGV resulting from a corrupted heap means that even trying to free other stuff on the heap maybe a hopeless exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Abnormal termination of your process does not lead to memory blocks that cannot be used by other processes (effectively meaning they are free), if they were allocated by it.

We allocate/free memory using OS-directives so that a non-buggy OS keeps track of mem chunks for each process and translates them into a contiguous virtual memory space. Upon a process-death, OS loader signals it, and all memory gets recalled. Things get complicated when processes share memory.

Peering processes, if not derived/launched/forked by you process (e.g. consider an external component serving many processes to access multimedia resources), may have created memory (e.g. buffer) to serve your process. Depending on the policy of ownership of these external components, that memory might not be free upon served-process death.

I advise you to try audit all memory committed before and after abnormal termination scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Only if your OS doesn't reclaim memory on program termination. DOS and its 'sticky memory' is an example of such an OS. On most modern OS not free()'ing on abnormal termination is a non-issue.

Comment: what kind of memory does DOS not reclaim on program termination?

Comment: Hrm.  Are you sure that is true?

Comment: I'm sure it's true for at least one variant of MSDOS and CP/M's BDOS - they had support for what was called 'sticky memory' which a program could allocate space on, and remained allocated even after it would terminate. Also, the TSR call in MSDOS achieved something similar, but I wouldn't consider it 'abnormal termination'.

Comment: If it's only MS-DOS and CP/M, that's okay for me. I do target free/libre systems only (and expect FreeDos to be intelligent enough)

Answer (score 0):

No, unless your program always terminates abnormally. :)
Anyway, the OS does a fine job freeing it up. In fact many lazy programmers don't even bother freeing things up with normal termination - but this makes detecting other memory leaks difficult (the ones that are a real problem).

Answer (score 0):

On abnormal termination you want to do as little processing as possible. Minimizing tinkering with the aborting process will mean you can get to as close to the reason for the abort as possible and any further processing can be seen as "contaminating" the process thus making it more difficult to debug.